# Why json_simple-1.1.jar doesn't deploy to folder WEB-INF\lib auto?

Tags: java, json, tomcat6

I use JSONObject and JSONArray in my project, eclipse run is ok after add  json_simple-1.1.jar to build path, but when I open my page in IE, I got error as below, I also found there is no  json_simple-1.1.jar in WEB-INF/lib, so I can copy file to there directly, but I am not sure why eclipse doesn't deploy it auto? is there any way to deploy jar file auto? I googled but no useful answer.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONArray
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2365)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1763)
    java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1259)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1257)
    java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1125)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:383)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:155)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptors(PropertyUtilsBean.java:896)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptors(PropertyUtilsBean.java:926)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtilsBean.java:801)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:937)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811)
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298)
    org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:816)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    com.gehc.nozomi.common.filter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I am using eclipse 3.4, there is J2EE Module Dependencies to config Deployment Assembly.